# Newly bought hardware won't boot, how to power up motherboard without cpu?

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, bios

[image]I have bought an ASRock A320-DGS motherboard and a Ryzen 5 2600 CPU.

After assembling all of the components together, when I tried to boot the machine it would not boot (PSU turns on and so does the CPU fan, no image on the motherboard DVI connected screen).

I tried removing it of the tower, trying to boot the motherboard from outside the box to try and rule out any short-circuit related problems.

I have tried removing HDD, memory and CPU to try and find out the cause of this.

When I try to start the machine, I get a two round 5 beeps from the motherboard.

I read online that I might need to update the ASRock firmware to get it to boot the Ryzen 5 CPU.

So I tried removing the CPU and tried to boot the motherboard hoping to get to the BIOS screen and see if I can update it.

However, still no image. I am not sure if I need to do something to get this to boot to the BIOS without CPU, if this is even possible, or what should I try in order to tray and trace the cause of this.

Thank you.

Comment: If I correctly understand, the Graphics Output port on AM4 boards is only applicable for those CPUs that have Integrated Graphics Processor on them. I.e. APUs and Ryzen G series. The Ryzen 5 2600 does require a discrete graphics card.

Comment: @pat2015 I will try that... if that is the issue, that is not clear at all, I assumed the onboard dvi would mean capability to display image from there...so many boards with integrated graphics, I would assume this to be the case.

Comment: "get this to boot to the BIOS without CPU, if this is even possible" No.

Comment: The AM4 Boards do not have Integrated Graphics, however they have Graphics output port to enable the compatible  AMD APUs to display output. Please check the specs here https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/A320M-DGS/index.asp#Specification see the asterix  against the Graphics Specs. It only says - Integrated AMD Radeon™ Vega Series Graphics in Ryzen Series APU*
- Integrated AMD Radeon™ R-Series Graphics in A-series APU*   Need for BIOS update might be a possibility, however before anything Ryzen 5 2600 does require discrete Graphics Card to display output on AM4 Boards.